# Replaceing <a href="mailto: with just email aadress

Tags: php, regex, mailto

I want to replace all "mailto:" links in html with plain emails.

```
In: text .... <a href="mailto:somebody@example.org">not needed</a> text
Out: text .... somebody@example.org text
```

I did this:

```
$str = preg_replace("/\<a.+href=\"mailto:(.*)\".+\<\/a\>/", "$1", $str);
```

But it fails if there are multiple emails in string or html inside "a" tag

```
In: <a href="mailto:hello@somedomain.org">not needed</a><a href="mailto:somebody@example.org"><font size="3">somebody@example.org</font></a>
Out: somebody@example.org">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your match **non-greedy** by adding `?` to quantifiers `+` and `*` as:

```
$str = preg_replace("/\<a.+?href=\"mailto:(.*?)\".+?\<\/a\>/", "$1", $str);
```

Also you need not escape `<` and `>` and since there are some `/` in the pattern its better to use a different delimiter and since you are not doing any variable interpolation inside the pattern, there is no need to enclose it in `"` this way you can avoid escaping `"` inside the pattern:

```
$str = preg_replace('#<a.+?href="mailto:(.*?)".+?</a>#', "$1", $str);
```

Comment: Thanks, non-greedy match does the job well & thanks for the escaping info.